# How do I cout string array in this way

Tags: c++, arrays, string, palindrome

So I decided to check if the word is palindrome. So I made 2 string, and I have to input word(like `"Hello"`).I don't understand how do I compare this 2 strings, and also I have an error with using `word.length` with variable `i`. How do I fix it? Is it necessary to change code or I can just change something in mine?

```
string word,s;
cin>>word;
for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
    s[i]=word[i];
}
if(s==word)
    cout<<1;
```

Comment: `s[i]=word[i];` is undefined behavior due to `s` being empty.

Comment: your title seems to be unrelated to the question

Comment: when you ask for help fixing compiler errors you should include the error message in the question

Comment: If you say `I have an error` it's not helpful, because for all we know the error could be you trying to compile it with Java compiler instead of c++ compiler, or trying to open this program in Sony Vegas Pro. Please put the error in the question body.

Comment: here is the error .       Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

Comment: you can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59290878/edit)

Comment: The error is due to saving an `unsigned long` (the result type of the `length()` member of `word`), to an `int`. Changing `int i` to `auto i` would solve it. So would throwing out the loop, and `s`, and just doing `std::cout << word == std::string(word.rbegin(), word.rend());`

Comment: BTW, please note that you don't need to create a reversed copy of a string to check if it's a palindrome. Just compare its elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there is no need to use an additional string to check whether a given string is a palindrome. You can perform such a check in a loop.

However using your approach you could write simpler. for example

```
if ( word == std::string( word.rbegin(), word.rend() ) ) std::cout << 1;
```

As for the error you are saying it seems that the compiler does not .like when you are comparing signed integer i with the unsigned integer value returned by the call word.length*().

Moreover as the string s is empty then you may not use the subscript operator

```
s[i]=word[i];
```

You could write either

```
s += word[i];
```

or

```
s.push_back( word[i] );
```

Preliminary you could reserve enough memory for the string s like

```
s.reserve( word.size() );
```